# can we forward request from one servlet to other servlet or jsp using sendRedirect within same application?

Tags: servlets, forward

Can we forward the request from one servlet to another servlet or jsp using sendRedirect within same application instead of RequestDispatcher.forward()?
I know that request is transfer to another resource to different domain or different server for further processing when we use sendRedirect but am not sure whether we can forward to another jsp or servlet within same application under same context.

Please clarify me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do `sendRedirect()` within the same application but in case of `sendRedirect()` a **new `request`** will be created so you will lose all the **attributes and parameters** of the request.

But when you do `forward()` it uses the same request.

If it's the same application prefer `forward()` it avoids the unnecessary trips in between client and server

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got it now.